# C macros: Jump to next label (using __COUNTER__?)

Tags: c, gcc, macros, label, goto

Context: I am trying to create macros to create some efficient coroutines. In my concept, the function has multiple passes (running, cleaning, checking). Currently I implement it using switch/case The running part is a happy path, basically a fallthrough in a switch. While the other passes need to be invoked only in error modes. I would like it so that a label can jump to next label in sequence.

```
step1: 
...
goto step2; // How to generate this statement? Equivalent of __COUNTER__+1
```

In other words macro code likle this:

```
BEGIN
AWAIT action1();
AWAIT action2();
AWAIT action3();
END
```

To become essentially

```
if (0) {
  if (pass == CLEANING) {
     clean1: 
     clean(1)
     goto clean2; // <-  
  } else ...
}
case 1:
action1()

if (0) {
  if (pass == CLEANING) {
     clean2:
     // no cleaning code here, compiler hopefully will optimize it out
     // jumping from step 1 to step 3
     goto clean3();  // <- 
  } else ...
}
case 2:
action2()

if (0) {
  if (pass == CLEANING) {
     clean3: 
     clean(3)
     goto clean4();  // <- 
  } else ...
}
case 3:
action3()

if (0) {
clean4: // complete
}
```

I tried different approaches using switch statements & extra cases. Also tried building a skiplist to dispatch to correct case. But i'd like to do it without dispatching my "passes" through switch, and "connect" them using gotos directly. Generating label with `__COUNTER__` is easy, but generating `goto label ## __COUNTER__ + 1` seems to be impossible.

Are there any other options? (Let's say using anything GCC offers)

- Jump table? The way i use macros, i can not build the jump table upfront because i dont know how many steps will be there
- Multi-pass jump table? Creating some code that runs the full length of function first to create jump table seems to work, but it does not get optimized out on -O1/O2/Og, at least nothing I tried made it usable. It worked for O3, but it was very inefficient on others, which was really not very good for my needs.
- Maybe if instead of incrementing `__COUNTER__` i could somehow have access to "previous" value, i could work it out, but that seems to require some sort of runtime stuff. Saving counter value as enum does not really give me a way to concat labels anyway.
- Using asm goto maybe? Is it possible to create label name dynamically like that? Using asm macro perhaps?
- Labels-as-references seem to have the same problem that `__COUNTER__ + 1` does not compute during preprocessing.
- Creating a ton of macros like `#define INCREMENT_3 4` seems to be the only idea that can actually work. But i'm afraid of running out of numbers. I dont understand exactly what does "translation unit" scope mean for `__COUNTER__` - it's can be potentially more than one file, right?

Comment: Switch+goto jumps hidden behind custom macro language built on preprocessor? You do understand that this will be nearly impossible to debug or pass the code reviews, right?

Comment: maybe just use `while` + `switch`: `while(...) switch(state) { case 0: ...; state=1; break; case 1: ... }`.

Comment: It's true that it's not easy to debug. But the way i'm writing it is that the macro is on the LHS of the expression. So debugger still works for user code. If the macros themselves are covered with tests, they in fact can reduce amount of issues and bugs. Since they are meant to solve quite common situations with asynchronous code, deferred blocks, state transitions, guards, nested state machines. Coding it by hand is actually more prone to error. Although I do not disagree that it's quite complex, but it can be a good choice in certain sitautions (e.g. I'm writing an embedded OS)

Comment: @tstanisl thanks. That's a decent solution and that's what I have now essentially. the issue with it is that I have a bit of disparity between certain "passes" like deferred blocks or guards being sparse (like once every 10 steps), while regular code is quite dense (8/10 steps). I am having to generate multiple case conditions per each macro invocation, and the ASM output of the jump table is not ideal in my case, wasting time just dispatching each case, when a lot of time there's nothing to run and it needs to immediately jump next one. So I'm trying to see if there're any alternatives

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to go with a set of `INCREMENT_X X+1` macros. Even though I know casual use of macros are bad, it allowed me to achieve very tight code even onlow level of optimizations. Gotos are wonderfully optimized.

I implemented a coroutine system that implements re-entrancy, guard checks, defer blocks (also re-entrant), ability to unwind progress. In addition it has optional analyze pass that determines what kind of actions will happen in the function. By keeping macros to LHS of expressions, all regular functions calls are easily debuggable.

```
    ENTER();
    printf("NO EVEN STEP LOL\n");
    AWAIT printf("Step %d\n", __LINE__);
    AWAIT printf("Step %d\n", __LINE__);
    // following expression will only run on function exit
    DEFER printf("Deferring %d\n", __LINE__);
    AWAIT printf("Step %d\n", __LINE__);
    // if guard check faills, the function rolls back to this point
    // running all defer blocks that were reached previously
    // it also prevents function to execute further
    GUARD !block;
    printf("!!!!Before defer\n");
    // following block will run either on function exit
    // or on guard fail if execution reached it
    DEFER {
        printf("In defer lol\n");
        // will suspend function based on value of await
        // this is the complicated case of defer block being async
        AWAIT await ? 666 : 1;
        AWAIT printf("UNDEFER %d\n", __LINE__);
        printf("/ In defer lol\n");
    }
    printf("/ defer\n");
    AWAIT printf("Step %d\n", __LINE__);
    AWAIT printf("Step %d\n", __LINE__);
    AWAIT printf("Step %d\n", __LINE__);
    // runs all defer blocks
    LEAVE();
```

Here's a control graph on O1, which is barely different from O3
[image]

-O1: https://godbolt.org/z/xfnPeKrq3
-Og: https://godbolt.org/z/GMnM6Gx7E